# Ee 3 and Php 7 and mamp

Tags: php, ee3, localhost

I switched my local install over to php 7 and when I tried to navigate to my ee install it threw a mysqli_connection.php error, that said this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

It seems MAMP doesn't create the correct file for php 7 to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking it up I found this solution that worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I thought I'd post this in case anyone else runs into this error.